# AWS Lambda: OSError, too many open files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I set 10 concurrency run for my Python lambda, and the lambda need to run for sometime to process 50K SQS messages.

Inside each lambda run, it always open and close a file.

```
file_content = None
if schema_filename:
    with open(schema_filename) as schema_file:
        file_content = schema_file.read()
...
```

But some lambda runs are showing the following error.

```
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/var/task/my_project/my.json'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you provide more details regarding the purpose of the file and the language that you were using? Would be interesting to see how do you read the file.

Comment: It was a schema definition file, and the lambda was in Python, I have shared the source code in the description.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is an OS limitation, I'm not so sure if we can adjust it using the following command:

```sh
ulimit -n 50000
```

You can give it a try by using `os` module:

```py
import os

os.system("ulimit -n 50000")
```

If the command above does not work, you might want to consider placing the file opening code where your application can benefit from a warm start?

```py
import os

file_content = None

# This stuff gets executed once and gets 
# shared across multiple invocations of a lambda instance.
with open(schema_filename) as schema_file:
  file_content = schema_file.read()

def handler(event, context):
```

Comment: AWS Lambda has a [file descriptor quota limit of 1,024](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html#function-configuration-deployment-and-execution) that can't be increased.